# Exception during applying a style

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resources, styles

I'm sure I'm struggling with something very basic, missing a very simple point...
But I just keep hitting the wall, so please help.

The problem is as follows.

If I define a certain style in the `<Window.Resources>` of the same Window where I apply it to controls - everything works just fine.
But since I want to reuse this style in a different window of my application, I tried to move the style out to some common location... And here the things stopped working.

If I put the style in Themes\Generic.xaml, the style doesn't get applied.

When I try to reference it from the original window by explicitly applying `Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}"` on the corresponding control (where "MyStyle" is the x:Key of the style) - I get an error

> The resource 'MyStyle' could not be resolved

If I put the style in a separate XAML file, and try to add it to MergedDictionaries in my App.xaml, I get a different problem: "'Resources' property has already been set on 'App'".
This is how I try to define it:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MergedDictionaries">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/MyStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
<Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not set the `x:Key` on the dictionary, otherwise it will be added as a resource which is not what you want, it should set the `Application.Resources` property instead.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Merged dictionaries -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- Other Resources -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I get the same error regardless.
The x:Key was added because VS doesn't like it when I mix ResourceDictionaris with and without keys...

Comment: @Alex: Are you adding resources outside? The code you showed should not cause any trouble (without the `x:Key`), you only may add other resources where i indicated it in my snippet.

Comment: Good catch. Indeed, I had a resource outside the ResourceDictionary.
Now that this is fixed - I still don't have the style applied from the external file :-(

Comment: @Alex: Do you reference it or is it applied implicitly?

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting.
What I see is that implicitly it doesn't get applied, but if I add it explicitly to one control (Style={DynamicResouce MyStyle}) - not only it works, but it works for *all* the controls in the window!
Is there a proper way to reference the external style in the Window.Resources section? I guess merging the style into the Window's styles dictionaries should achieve the same result?

Comment: @Alex: Normally implicit application should work just fine via the merged dictionaries in the application resources, further they are applied even to controls inside ControlTemplates, this is one reason they are normally used for themes. You should not need to reference the styles in the windows either as they should be applied throughout the application. Do you perhaps override the styles locally?

Comment: I don't think so... This is the whole point of moving the style to an external file.